# How to perform complex update on hstore column in postgres using ruby?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

I have this sql query in ruby to update an hstore column in postgres

```
query = %Q{UPDATE accounts SET favorites =
    hstore(ARRAY['favorite_book', user.book, 'favorite_movie', user.movie])
    FROM (VALUES #{data} ) AS user(id_str, favorite_book, favorite_movie)
    WHERE accounts.original_id_str = user.id_str;}
```

where data is a string that looks like this

```
data = "('3082633', 'FavoriteBook1', 'FavoriteMovie1'),('1768517', 'FavoriteBook2', 'FavoriteMovie2'),('8245997', 'FavoriteBook3', 'FavoriteMovie3')"
```

Right now I'm updating the database table by calling

```
Account.connection.execute(query)
```

But is there a way to convert as much of the query as possible to ruby instead of sql? For example, something like

```
add_to_hstore = %(favorites = hstore(?, ?))
Account.update_all([add_to_hstore, "favorite_book", "LOTR"])
```

but instead use the values from the 'data' variable.

Comment: Why are you using hstore for this? Looks like a separate table would be suitable and probably easier to work with.

Comment: This is a generalization of the database model. We have other hstore columns that store the metadata of a photo for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are gems for hstore like this one : https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore

or you use a simple update by creating you own account object : 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/new

Comment: We are using the hstore gem. The problem is that there are not a lot of options for updating hstore in ruby. We can do one of two things: 1) Update individual rows one at a time with different data (ie data.map{ |id, book, movie| Account.where(origin_id_str: id).update("favorites = hstore("...")) }, but this would take a lot of database calls which we want to avoid. 2) Update all the rows in the table using one database call, but that makes it impossible to apply different values to each of the rows unless we write the query in sql.